Session not Persist in WKWebview stored in local storage when app killed
I'm using Webview in SwiftUI view into my application with the default URL set to the home page. However, if the user is not logged in or if the session has expired, the user is redirected to the login page. When I log in using credentials, it correctly shows the home page.
The problem occurs when I kill the app and then reopen it. Instead of displaying the home page, it shows the login page again. It seems that the session is not persisting after the app is killed.
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct AccountWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    var url: URL
    var isLoading: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
        
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        
        let _wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        _wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator
        
        return _wkwebview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: AccountWebView

        init(_ parent: AccountWebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.parent.isLoading.wrappedValue = false
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            self.parent.isLoading.wrappedValue = false
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            self.parent.isLoading.wrappedValue = false
        }

    }
}

